# What is the format of a data dictionary?

Tags: database

Are there any standard examples/ samples of data dictionaries that document a database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The official standard is [ISO/IEC 11179](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_11179) ... which will make your head hurt and refers to semantic elements of the documented data-model when we usually need both semantic and physical (tables, fields etc.) documentation in a 'real world' data dictionary.

Personally, I favour (however you implement this is up to you) physical and optionally logical Entity-Relationship models on the front-page, entry screen or wherever a user of the Data Dictionary first 'hits' (This provides a meta layer to the detail beneath).

Then for each table:

**Table Name** [Physical | Logical]

**Table description** (content, granularity, 'periodicity' (if there
   is one, the time period which applies to the data contained in the table),
   source)

Then for each column:

> > **Column Name**
> >
> > **Column Description**
> >
> > **Column Datatype**
> >
> > **Column Size in Bytes**
> >
> > [Optional] **Other Column Details**... nullable, triggers, source

**Relationships**   Constraint name | 'Other' Table | Cardinality | Type
   etc.

**Indexes**   Name | Column
   Membership | Type etc.

...Obviously, that's a 'less is more' approach to defining a data dictionary! I think the key is providing an easy way in (through the ER) model, rather than just a long, labourious list of tables and columns.

Comment: what for do we create data dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your database - for relational database the Data Definition Language of SQL is standardized as part of the corresponding ISO standards for SQL.

For NoSQL and Graph Database get more difficult because these are some times "schema free" by definition. You might find more pointers when you look for LinkML and https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33103120/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a standard way of doing it.

Oracle uses a series of objects all starting with `DBA_*`.  For example, DBA_TABLES, DBA_TAB_COLUMNS, etc.  You can do `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'DBA%'` to get a list.

If you don't have privs, there is an analogous series of objects for users, called `USER_TABLES`, `USER_VIEWS`, `USER_TAB_COLS`, etc.